# Android 9 Can you suggest a background service

Tags: java, android

how can i do a background service that will run every 5 minutes also when the app is close? I want that every 5 minutes will do more check and it will choose if show a notification message or not

I used this but with android 9 doesn't work anymore

```
public Background() {
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    onTaskRemoved(intent);

    return START_STICKY;
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implement");
}

public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    startService(restartServiceIntent);
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
                         //CODE HERE
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(300000); //sleep 5 minutes 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
};



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    new Thread(runnable).start();

    //start a separate thread and start listening to your network object

        //Log.i("PROVA SERVICE", "Evento n."+n++);
        System.out.println("BackgroundService");

}
```

Comment: You might want to associate your service with AlarmManager to triger your service. but every five minutes is not a good idea, you might want to rethink how you want to design your background

Comment: like @PankajNimgade said u can use AlarmManager but. if u can do in 15 minute better with WorkManager

Comment: AlarmManager doesn't work if the app is closed? Why? There is a solution?